# Programmatically setting a list identifier

Tags: java, android, list, identifier

A java class contains an instance variable which is a `List`.
I need to set the type of object that this `List` holds in a `String` variable.

`private List<VARIABLE> myList;
 String VARIABLE = "BasicDegreeClass";`

Is this allowed to do in JAVA If so, how can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not Sure what exactly is your case . Will this work ? `class Test<T>{
        List<T> list;
    }`.

Comment: I wanted to do something like this `List<VARIABLE> myList = new ArrayList<VARIABLE>();`

Comment: Yeah this is what i have did above . Use a Generic Type .

Comment: Not sure what your asking, but you better use [Java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Or you might use something like `String variableType = myList.get(index).class.getName()`. But make sure your list is initialized (not null) and not empty, and note that you should never declare a package-private variable with upper-case identifier name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you will have to create a List where T is the Type of objects contained in the list.

So, your code should read as

`private List<T> myList;`

From the javadoc,

> `<T> the type of elements in this list.`

In your case, the compiler will not know the type of elements that is to be added to your list and hence it won't work.

However you can use `List<Object>` as an alternate, but that is a generally code-smell in long run and very difficult to maintain

- It kills the idea of generics.
- Makes your code prone to ClassCastException.
- In a perfect world and even if you are safe while adding elements,
  you will need to suppress warning everywhere and need to cast back to
  the type.

**Proper Solution** : You can write an interface, which all your objects of the ArrayList will adhere to. Proceed with something like

```
List<'YOUR INTERFACE TYPE HERE'> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Don't you need to worry of the object type inside the list. Hope this helps!

If you are too specific to save in String, here is a workaround.

```
public static <T> List<T> getCastedList(List<Object> objList, Class<T> clazz) {
        List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
        if (objList != null) {
            for (Object object : objList) {
                if (object != null && clazz.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
                    newList.add((T) object);
                }
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

And call this as

```
getCastedList(myList, Class.forName(VARIABLE));
```

Comment: Glad to hear @NiazAhsan :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use generics like this

`private List<T> myList;`

[documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

but it is possible to use a string to represent a class name or act as a unique identifier, given you support this yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can create `List` only with `class` not `primitive types` or its values.

Example:-

```
List<Integer> a =  new ArrayList<>();
List<YourObject> obj = new ArrayList<>();
```

But if your will  try with `primitive types` then you will get.

[image]